# Change background image of <li> on click of <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor, background-image

**html:**

```
 <ul>
    <li id="Co" class="libgc" ><b>CO</b></li>
    <li id="NSCO" class="libgc active"><span> <a href="#NSale.php" target="homeFrame" class="aclass">NSale</a></span></li>
 </ul>
```

**css:**

```
.libgc {
background-color: #CCC;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
text-align: center;
background-image: url(../images/pcnav.png);
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
 $("li").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url("images/btnSelectedTab.png")');
    $(this).css('color','black');
  });

 });
```

Problem : When I click on first link its background image is changed, but again next time when I click on other link,its background is also changed, & first links background is also similar.(Meant when I click on 2nd link, 1st links image should get back to the basic once.)

How to reset background image to the previous one,when I click on some other links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

CSS for the new active class is

```
li.active {
   background-image: url(../images/btnSelectedTab.png);
   color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a class for what you wish the active `li` tag to look like; and use the following:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

This should affect only list items within the same `ul` tag.